# DSE solr found rows with expired columns

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-search

running DSE 4.8.10 - I have 3 DSE Search nodes in my cluster, RF=3. I'm seeing some messages in system.log like those below. It seems they always come after a compaction. Is there a problem with the solr indexes or is there at least an explanation of these messages?

`INFO  [CompactionExecutor:12] 2016-11-14 23:09:31,243  CompactionTask.java:274 - Compacted 4 sstables to [/data/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ka-13314,].  1,564 bytes to 1,378 (~88% of original) in 17ms = 0.077304MB/s.  4 total partitions merged to 1.  Partition merge counts were {4:1, }
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,008  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,053  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,144  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,187  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,230  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,270  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,311  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,353  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,395  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,436  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,478  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,519  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,559  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,600  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,640  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 200 rows with expired columns.
INFO  [Solr TTL scheduler-0] 2016-11-14 23:09:36,681  AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java:1689 - Found 31 rows with expired columns.`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have some TTL set on your data.

`If you want to expire data in a cassandra, you don’t have much choice: you need a periodic task that somehow finds expired data and removes it. With lots of data, keeping this efficient can be a challenge. Cassandra actually includes a great opportunity for that kind of job: compaction. Compaction already goes through your data periodically, throwing away old versions of your data, so it is really easy and cheap to use it for data expiration.`

This might be the reason why you see those messages only after compaction.

You can read more here :
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-expiring-columns